# Animating an Array of UIViews

Tags: objective-c, arrays, animation, uiview, calayer

I have an array of UIViews which I animate with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<(int)viewArray.count; i++) {
    UIView *view = [viewArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CALayer *layer = view.layer;

    //animate the layer

}
```

My question is, is there any way to have a delay between every animation, so that, for example, it animates one UIView in the array and the next animation starts after 0.2 seconds or so? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try the following

```
float timeDelay = 0.2
float duration = YOUR_DURATION
for (int i = 0; i<(int)viewArray.count; i++) {
    UIView *view = [viewArray objectAtIndex:i];

    //animate the layer
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:(i+1)*timeDelay
            options: {Check UIView Class Reference on developer.apple.com}
            animations:^{
                   [view.layer fantastic animation here];
            } completion^(BOOL finised){
                   if(finished){
                     //Leave blank if nothing, good practice to implement debuging here or post  animation processes here (like removing a subview from a super)
                   }
            }];

}
```

Keep in mind that if u send your program the the background it may break your animations so make sure u recall this method in ur app Delegates:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Would there be a way to define the list of animations in the `for` loop, and then call [UIView animateWithDuration] only once?  Would that method be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Use this guy:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

use the second parameter. Inside your loop, call that function, passing an every-increasing number to that parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but now it doesn't animate at all.. I'm new to this, so just to clarify, I do call this with `[self animateWithDuration:5 delay:i ...etc`, right? Thanks again!

Comment: [UIView animate...]  also, it's for animating UIView properties. Not sure for CALayer properties.